# Lebesgue differentiation theorem in weighted Lebesgue spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

It is well known that $$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\|f\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}{\|\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}=|f(x)|$$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $1\leq p< \infty$. Here $\chi_{B(x,r)}$ denotes the characteristic function of the open ball $B(x,r)$. I wonder whether there is an analogue of this property in weighted Lebesgue spaces, that is, $$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow0}\dfrac{\|f\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{p}^{w}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}{\|\chi_{B(x,r)}\|_{L_{p}^{w}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}}=|f(x)| $$ for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?

More generally, is there a version of Lebesgue differentiation theorem for general measures?

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of theory connected to those things. I took a course on that some years ago, but the only thing I remember is that everything revolves around this concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muckenhoupt_weights

Comment: This is the abstract of the course: http://www.icmat.es/NTHA/courses/perez.html It doesn't say much, but I hope it might help nonetheless. It is possible that the speaker has some lecture notes somewhere on the Internet.

Comment: Does this result hold for general $p$? It seems that the denominator is less dependent on $p$ (since \chi^p = \chi) that the numerator (where you get $f^p \neq f$)

Answer (score 0):

You always have 
$$
  f_*(A) \leq \frac{1}{\mu(A)}\int_A f\,\mathrm d\mu \leq f^*(A) 
$$
where $f_*(A)$ and $f^*(A)$ are the $\inf$ and $\sup$ of $f$ on $A$. As soon as you can assure that they converge as $A$ goes to a single point, you get your result.

Comment: The proof of classical Lebesgue differentiation theorem is more complicated, but your proof is too short. Could it be something that was overlooked. If i choose $d\mu=w(x)dx$ then, the claim is true for all weight functions. But the comments are so to say that this would be true for weight functions from Muckenhoupt class.